# How to add a javascript file in GWT host HTML?

Tags: gwt

I am trying to add a .js file https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/#Basic_Usage to my GWT project.

I have made the entry in my host HTML:

I pasted the .js file in /src/main/resources/ and added it to my build path.

I am getting Error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)       http://localhost:8080/src/main/resources/geoxml3.js

I found a very complicated solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1660342/768894

Can someone please help me do it in some simple steps.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy this file to your `/war` folder. Then you can simply add this to your host page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="geoxml3.js"></script>
```

Comment: Won't this break once I redeploy my war? There should be a way to add the js file such that it always gets included in the war file. Something that is mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20323708/768894

Comment: Why would it break? As long as you do not delete this file, it will stay there.

Comment: It is quite strange but my project seems to have no /war folder... :( It is a maven project.

Comment: You must have some public folder - it is the same folder where your host HTML file is.

Comment: Super!! it works and I verified by opening the created war file and it was threre..thanks a bunch!!

Comment: I know we are adding this script tag in head section,but its not a good way as per rule.Is there any problem if we add this script tag under body section.Why we need to add this in head section?any idea?